# What this word "nip" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> There's a **nip** in the air this morning.
>
> The Dog was **nipping** on a bone.

Is it the same word in both?

I'm asking about this word **nip**.

I couldn't understand it, and I am looking for more Examples.

Is there another context to this **nip**  word

Comment: Did you try to look this word up in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but I can't put the first one in another sentence.

Comment: Can I say the weather is nip this night?

Comment: how can I close a Question if there is no answer or should I just delete it?

Comment: Given the distinct contexts, this seems to be answerable with a dictionary (M-W: [nip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nip)). Please [edit] your post to explain why the dictionary was not helpful. Please see [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Comment: @Jacob.  These are examples of the *literal* and *figurative* definitions of the term.  "To nip" is similar to "to bite".  A dog can literally *nip* at a bone  in the same way that cold weather can figuratively feel like it's *nipping* at your skin.

Comment: @Jacob:   **nip** is not an adjective, but a verb, so no, you cannot say "The weather is nip".  Rather, the weather is **nippy**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In very cold air, exposed parts of the body, especially the face, nose and ears, can feel as if they are being nipped (pinched or bitten). Very cold weather is also said to be 'biting'.

> Nip (verb)
>
> to affect sharply and painfully, as extreme cold does
>   The cold was nipping at our faces.
>   The cold nipped our faces.

[Nip](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/nip)

Comment: With all due respect, a person is not pinching them. It can feel like a person is being pinched by another person.

Comment: That is why I wrote "as if". - _**As if/though** B2 used to describe how a situation seems to be:._  [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-if-though)

Comment: Personally, I would be more explicit: It feels like a person is being pinched by another; the cold air is like a person.

Comment: Not just a person. The bite of a small animal is also a nip - I have a Jack Russell terrier, and they are known to be "nippers". Also being constricted in a narrow space can nip, thus restricting the term to people is being somewhat narrow.

Comment: +1. Let's agree that anything with teeth can nip: toddlers, pups, tiling tools, etc.

Comment: Doors and drawers can nip when being closed.

Comment: Is there a guide on how to close a topic or they all should stay open?

Comment: ♫ Jack Frost nipping at your nose...

Comment: With his fingers made of icicles.

Comment: @Jacob, a question is only closed, or 'put on hold', if it is off-topic or wrong in some way. A question is not closed merely if the original questioner feels that it has been adequately answered.